# Ruby on Rails - recover password on email NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, password-recovery

I'm setting up a reset password feature. Upon submission an email will be sent with a reset password link. I'm doing this from scratch as described in [railscast episode 274](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password). However, when I submit my email I get this error.

### NoMethodError in PasswordResetsController#create

```
undefined method `password_reset_sent_at=' for # <User:0xa9fd828>

app/models/user.rb:26:in `send_password_reset'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

**Request**

**Parameters:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"HnuB/J15XZtz3MTCd25MCwm06M3G2AbcRH+cFxzdj+8=",
"email"=>"cauterise@gmail.com",
"commit"=>"Reset Password"}
```

The development log says the same thing as above ^

**app/models/user.rb**

```
def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end

def generate_token(column)
  begin
  self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

**app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb**

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  user.send_password_reset if user
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions."
end

def edit
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password reset has expired."
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset!"
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
```

**app/vies/password_resets/new,html.haml**

```
%h1 Reset Password
= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do
  .field
    = label_tag :email
    = text_field_tag :email, params[:email]
  .actions
    = submit_tag "Reset Password"
  end
```

I ALREADY DID rake:db:reset and rake:db:migrate AND RESET SERVER.

EDIT: db USER

- id    integer primary key
- email varchar(255)
- password_hash   varchar(255)
- password_salt    varchar(255)
- created_at    datetime
- updated_at    datetime
- auth_token    varchar(255)
- password_reset_token varchar(255)
- password_reset_send_at   datetime

Comment: So did you add a password_reset_sent_at column to your User model?

Comment: show what table `users` looks like in your db/schema.rb

Comment: Ahhhh good call i have it set to password_reset_send_at  I should change the send to sent right? But how do I change that.

Comment: I included the users db in edit

Comment: to change it create a migration with `rename_column :users, :password_reset_send_at, :password_reset_sent_at`  or just edit the migration that created it wrong  and `rake db:reset && rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the your database users column password_reset_send_at should be password_reset_sent_at. You can change this by going into the migration files and do that simple change then running

```
$ rake db:reset
$ rake db:migrate
```